# Adobe CQ 6.1 New Components don't appear

Tags: adobe, aem

When I go to insert a new component, the window doesn't display any options. Does anyone know the reason why?

I'm using Adobe CQ 6.1 and Sightly

My html file:

```html
<div data-sly-resource="${@path='par', resourceType='foundation/components/parsys'}"></div>
```

[What happens when i try to insert a new component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ThyXR.jpg)

Comment: Have you checked the design mode if there any components enabled for your paragraph system?

Comment: Yes, i have . I allowed all components for the parsys

Comment: Your component should have dialog defined. Also another debug tip is that your component node name and component title should not be same (consider it as a old defect)

Comment: Apparently it's an AEM bug. I selected the option to allow all components of General Group and it didn't work. When i unchecked this option and selected all check-boxes individually, it worked.